# Array of Strings into an ArrayList of Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I would like to convert an Array of Strings into an ArrayList of `ArrayList`, where the inner `ArrayList` has a dynamic number of elements. Who can help ? Thanks in advance

```
String[] sentences = {"hello","how are you","i am fine","and you ?","thank you"}
//Output with number of elements = 2
["hello","how are you"]
["i am fine","and you ?"]
["thank you"]
//Output with number of elements = 3
["hello","how are you","i am fine"]
["and you ?","thank you"]
```

Comment: What is the diff. between number of elements = 2 and 3 ?

Comment: @bibuche Do you want code ?

Comment: the number of elements has to be dynamic. The total number of sentences is 5. With number of elements = 2 we get 2,2,1. with number of elements = 3 we get 3,2 as number of strings in the inner Arraylist.

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] sentences = {"hello", "how are you", "i am fine", "and you ?", "thank you"};
    System.out.println(split(2,sentences));
    System.out.println(split(3,sentences));
}

public static List<List<String>> split(int numberOfElements, String[] sentences) {
    List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    int index = 0;
    for (String sentence : sentences) {
        if (index % numberOfElements == 0) {
            lists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        lists.get(index / numberOfElements).add(sentences[index]);
        index++;
    }
    return lists;
}
```

Output:

```
[[hello, how are you], [i am fine, and you ?], [thank you]]
[[hello, how are you, i am fine], [and you ?, thank you]]
```

Comment: Thank you very very much both! It's exactly what I want. But I wonder what of both programs is the fastest?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String[] sentences = { "hello", "how are you", "i am fine", "and you ?", "thank you" };

   List<List<String>> convertIntoList = convertIntoList(sentences, 2);
   System.out.println(convertIntoList);

   convertIntoList = convertIntoList(sentences, 3);
   System.out.println(convertIntoList);
}


private static List<List<String>> convertIntoList(String[] sentences, int nbElement) {
   List<List<String>> listOfListTarget = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
   int currentIndex = 0;

   while (currentIndex < sentences.length) {

    int nextIndex = currentIndex + nbElement;
    if (nextIndex > sentences.length) {
      nextIndex = sentences.length;
    }
    final String[] copyOfRange = Arrays.copyOfRange(sentences, currentIndex, nextIndex);
    List<String> subList = new ArrayList<String>();
    subList.addAll(Arrays.asList(copyOfRange));
    listOfListTarget.add(subList);
    currentIndex+=nbElement;
  }
  return listOfListTarget;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much both! It's exactly what I want. But I wonder what of both programs is the fastest?

Answer (score 0):

Is this is a homework?

So you have an array of strings, and you want to create a List> with that, with each inner List containing at most x number of elements.

To get x number of elements and put them in a List, you can do a simple for loop.

```
String[] myStringArray = { ... };
List<String> myListOfString = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<x; i++) {
    myListOfString.add(myStringArray[i]);
}
```

So for example if you have these values

```
String[] myStringArray = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
x = 2;
```

You'll get the following list using the above loop:

```
["a", "b"]
```

Great! But we need to get all the contents of the `myStringArray`! How do we do that? Then let's do the first step, we iterate through all the contents of the array. We can do that like this.

```
int i=0; 
while(i < myStringArray.length) {
    System.out.println(myStringArray[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Which will output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

This doesn't solve the problem... but at least we know how to iterate the whole thing. The next step is to get x of them. Sounds simple right? So basically we need to create a list of x from the contents. Maybe we can use the logic we created a few examples back to solve the problem.

```
// Create list of list of string here
int i = 0;
while(i < myStringArray.length) {
  // Create list of string here
  for(int j=0; j<x; j++) {
      // Add myStringArray[j] to list of string here
  }
  // Add the list of string to the list of list of string here
  i++;
}
```

Easy right? No. This gives the following lists:

```
["a", "b"]
["a", "b"]
["a", "b"]
["a", "b"]
["a", "b"]
```

Why? In the first loop, we are iterating up to how many is in the array. In the second loop, we are adding element 0 and 1 to a list. Obviously it wouldn't work. The second loop needs to be aware that it should not add previously added elements, and at the same time the first loop needs to be aware of what the second loop is doing. So you might think, maybe we can use the `int i` to indicate where the second loop should start?

```
int i = 0;
while(i<myStringArray.length) {
    while(i<x) {
        // add myStringArray[i];
        i++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Unfortunately, using the same values as previous, this will only give the following list

```
["a", "b"]
```

Because `i` is iterating through the whole array. So when it goes from 0 to length, whatever the value of i is used on the second array. When it loops again, `i` becomes 1, so the start of the second loop is at 1.

We need a separate variable to do the counting, while still keeping in mind where we currently are in the second loop.

```
int i = 0;
while(i<myStringArray.length) {
    int count = 0;
    while(count < x) {
        // Add myStringArray[count+i] to list of string
        count++;
    }
    // Add to list of list of string
    i += count + 1; // Need to be aware of how much we have processed
}
```

This will do what we want, but unfortunately we can get in trouble at certain values. Say `x` is 10 and `myStringArray` is only of length 2. This will throw an exception because when it reaches the point of count+i = 3, that index doesn't exist anymore. The second loop also needs to be aware of how much is still remaining.

Finally we'll have the following code

```
int i = 0;
while(i<myStringArray.length) {
    int count = 0;
    while(count < x && count+i < myStringArray.length) {
        // Add myStringArray[count+i] to list of string
    }
    // Add to list of list of string
    i += count; // Need to be aware of how much we have processed
}
```

Which will give

```
["a", "b"]
["c", "d"]
["e"]
```

Edit: Next time try to put some code that you tried something.